# What are applications of convexity in sciences?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

What are applications of convex sets and the notion of convexity in mathematics and science?

This question have been already post as:

- [What are the applications of convex sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2016737/378968)
- [What are the main uses of Convex Functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/462949/378968)

but I wanted to know the relationship with other sciences while previous mentioned questions can be correctly answered just as: *for optimization theory*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convexity is important in quantum information theory. Take a look at

- Ingemar Bengtsson, Karol Zyczkowski, [Geometry of quantum states: an introduction to quantum entanglement](http://www.caam.rice.edu/~yad1/miscellaneous/References/Physics/Bengtsson%20I.,%20Zyczkowski%20C.%20Geometry%20of%20quantum%20states.pdf), Cambridge University Press, December 2007.
- John Watrous, [Semidefinite programming in the theory of quantum information](http://www.uoguelph.ca/quigs/cssqi14/Slides/SDP.Handout.pdf).