# Triangle's circumcircle inequality: Is it suitable for high schoolers?

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, circles, geometric-inequalities

I want to give this problem to high schooler students and I want to check if it is suitable for high school level.

> Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be the sides of a triangle and $R$ be the triangle's circumcircle's radius. Prove that 
>   $$A+B+C\leq 3\sqrt{3}\,R$$

I would also like to get some insights on how people tend to approach this kind of problem, Your solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Note, in the future, I believe the [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) site may be a more appropriate place to ask these types of questions.

Comment: Also, it's probably important that you specify in which country you're planning to introduce this problem, as there are definite differences in high school curricula across the world.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks guys! This is for Indonesian students. Will check the website, thanks.

Comment: Also, what prerequisites do we assume your students have? Do they know the sine rule, for example?

Comment: Or, do they know Hero's formula?

Comment: I'm trying using cosine rule but I'm stuck. Too tired to continue trying

Comment: The solution I most quickly came up with involved applying Jensen's inequality on the function $f(x) = -\sin x$ which is convex on $[0, \pi]$.  Not that I'd expect many high school students to know Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja You're welcome. As not everybody reads the comments, please update your question to at least indicate it's for Indonesian students, plus possibly also give some indications about what the students can be expected to know and/or not know as most people here will not be familiar with the Indonesian education system.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja: It would help if you gave the solution *you* had in mind. This will keep people from duplicating that answer and will also give some sense of what tools you're expecting students to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'd start by rewriting the inequality by the sine rule (here $\alpha$ is the angle opposite of side $A$, and so on):

$$ \sin \alpha + \sin \beta + \sin \gamma \le \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2},$$

so that is what we now want to prove; by Jensen's inequality (since $\sin x$ is concave in $[0, \pi]$), we have that

$$\sin \alpha + \sin \beta + \sin \gamma \le 3 \sin \frac{\alpha + \beta + \gamma}{3} = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

This is a proof without using any trigonometry, it only need
[Cauchy Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) and a little bit of vector algebra over the plane.

Instead of capital letters, I will use $a, b, c$ to denote the sides of the triangle. I will reserve $A,B,C$ for the vertices of triangle and choose a coordinate system where circumcenter is located at origin. i.e. $|A| = |B| = |C| = R$.

By Cauchy Schwartz, we have

$$a + b + c = a \cdot 1 + b \cdot 1 + c\cdot 1 \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2}$$
Since
$$\begin{align}a^2 + b^2 + c^2 &= |B-C|^2 + |C-A|^2 + |A-B|^2\\
&= 2(|A|^2 + |B|^2 + |C^2|) - 2(B\cdot C + C\cdot A + A\cdot B)\\
&= 3(|A|^2 + |B|^2 + |C^2|) - |A+B+C|^2\\
&\le 9R^2\end{align}$$

We find $$a+ b + c \le \sqrt{9R^2}\cdot\sqrt{3} = 3\sqrt{3}R$$

Comment: [+1] A tiny tiny detail : the (Hermann) Schwarz (in Cauchy Schwarz) has no "t" in its name, whereas (Laurent) Schwartz, the "distributions' man" has a "t".

Comment: @JeanMarie oops, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard notation we need to prove that:
$$a+b+c\leq3\sqrt3\cdot\frac{abc}{4S}$$ or
$$27a^2b^2c^2\geq(a+b+c)^3\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c).$$
Now, let $a=y+z,$ $b=x+z$ and $c=x+y.$

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that
$$27\prod_{cyc}(x+y)\geq64(x+y+z)^3xyz.$$
But $$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\geq\frac{8}{9}(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)$$ it's
$$\sum_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that
$$(xy+xz+yz)^2\geq3(x+y+z)xyz,$$ which is
$$\sum_{cyc}z^2(x-y)^2\geq0.$$